# What page is it if there parameters but no explicit page for php

Tags: php, url, parameters

This is a beginner question; while Googling, I could not find the answer.

I understand that if I have a URL like this for a PHP page:

```
http://blah.tld/somearea/myfile.php?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

That the page receiving the parameters *foo* and *bar* is `myfile.php`, but if I have a URL like this, what page is receiving the parameters:

```
http://blah.tld/somearea/?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

Is it `index.php` under whatever `/somearea` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actual program/file is called depends on the configuration of the web server.  For example, in Apache, there's configuration parameter `DirectoryIndex`, which indicates what is called by default if no file is specified, for example,

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

will ensure that `index.php` is called in the above scenario.  Moreover, this configuration can be set per directory so that in different directories different files/scripts will be invoked.  Without knowing how the target server is configured, it is not possible to answer this question.

Comment: Cheers. So I was right in my assumption that it will often be index.php - just not necessarily because of server configuration variance.

Comment: @SamSaint-Pettersen For a php app, most often it'll be index.php, correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is a server setting. For instance in Apache the setting is [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html). Usually on a PHP server, the default is **index.php**.

If PHP is not installed, the default would be **index.html** or **index.htm**. On a ASP server the default would be **default.aspx**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in that case index.php will receive parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same file that is used when `http://blah.tld/somearea/` is requested.

It may be `index.php`, or any other file.  It may not be a file itself, but a function in a separate file if a framework is being used.

Comment: Cheers. I think in my case it's probably going to be index.php, but I can check the server settings as suggested by the other posters if not.

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing but a re written URL using `.htaccess` so yes, you can and you've to fetch the GET params in the same way, so on `index.php` it will be

```
echo $_GET['param1'].' '.$_GET['param2']; //Will output foo bar
```